# C# - How to generate a list of file names and sub directories in a directory with creation date

Tags: c#, file, directory

I am trying to generate a list of all the files present in a directory and its sub-directories along with their creation date. The date and file name to be separated by "::"

I tried the below code but its taking time when the number of files are huge. Can anyone suggest me a better approach/ optimise the code??

I am even getting the "Access to the file denied" exception with the below approach, for some of the files in C Drive.

```
DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo[] dir = dir1.GetDirectories();
StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter("Test.lst");
foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dir)
{
    try
    {
        FileInfo[] file = di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var f in file)
        {
            write.WriteLine(f.FullName + "::" + f.CreationTime.ToShortDateString());
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
write.Flush();
write.Close();
```

Comment: I've updated my answer below with a solution that should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo( "c:\path" );
var entries = dirinfo.GetFileSystemInfos( "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories )
    .Select( t => string.Format( "{0}::{1}", t.FullName, t.CreationTime );
```

Comment: I am using .NET ver 3.5 and SearchOption.AllDirectories parameter is not available with GetFileSystemInfos, hence its not listing the files in sub directories. Could you pls provide some diffrent approach.

Answer (score 1):

Or when you're just lookin for the path you can do

```
Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should use the new [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) overloads in order to avoid getting the entire list in memory.

```
foreach (var f in di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
    write.WriteLine(f.FullName + "::" + f.CreationTime.ToShortDateString());
}
```

You can further optimize your code by writing each line as it is enumerated over. You can avoid the stream manipulation all together. Your entire routine becomes just a few lines:

```
public static void GenerateList(String dirPath, String fileName) {
    var dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);

    try {
        var lines = from f in dir1.EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    select f.FullName + "::" + f.CreationTime.ToShortDateString();

        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE

Ok, so not having .Net 4.0 is a bummer. However, **you could write your own class to enumerate a file system without too much trouble**. Here is one I just wrote that you can play with, and it only uses API calls that are already available to **.Net 3.5**

```
public class FileSystemInfoEnumerator: IEnumerator<FileSystemInfo>, IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> {
  private const string DefaultSearchPattern = "*.*";

  private String InitialPath { get; set; }
  private String SearchPattern { get; set; }
  private SearchOption SearchOptions { get; set; }
  private Stack<IEnumerator<FileSystemInfo>> EnumeratorStack { get; set; }

  private Action<Exception> ErrorHandler { get; set; }

  public FileSystemInfoEnumerator(String path, String pattern = DefaultSearchPattern, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, Action<Exception> errorHandler = null) {

     if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
        throw new ArgumentException("path cannot be null or empty");

     var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

     if(!dirInfo.Exists)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("File or Directory \"{0}\" does not exist", dirInfo.FullName));

     InitialPath = dirInfo.FullName;
     SearchOptions = searchOption;

     if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pattern)) {
        pattern = DefaultSearchPattern;
     }

     ErrorHandler = errorHandler ?? DefaultErrorHandler;
     EnumeratorStack = new Stack<IEnumerator<FileSystemInfo>>();
     SearchPattern = pattern;
     EnumeratorStack.Push(GetDirectoryEnumerator(new DirectoryInfo(InitialPath)));
  }

  private void DefaultErrorHandler(Exception ex) {
     throw ex;
  }

  private IEnumerator<FileSystemInfo> GetDirectoryEnumerator(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo) {
     var infos = new List<FileSystemInfo>();

     try {
        if (directoryInfo != null) {
           var info = directoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos(SearchPattern);
           infos.AddRange(info);
        }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
        ErrorHandler(ex);
     }

     return infos.GetEnumerator();
  }

  public void Dispose() {
     foreach (var enumerator in EnumeratorStack) {
        enumerator.Reset();
        enumerator.Dispose();
     }
  }

  public bool MoveNext() {
     var current = Current;

     if (ShouldRecurse(current)) {
        EnumeratorStack.Push(GetDirectoryEnumerator(current as DirectoryInfo));
     }

     var moveNextSuccess = TopEnumerator.MoveNext();

     while(!moveNextSuccess && TopEnumerator != null) {
        EnumeratorStack.Pop();

        moveNextSuccess = TopEnumerator != null && TopEnumerator.MoveNext();
     }

     return moveNextSuccess;
  }

  public void Reset() {
     EnumeratorStack.Clear();
     EnumeratorStack.Push(GetDirectoryEnumerator(new DirectoryInfo(InitialPath)));
  }

  public FileSystemInfo Current {
     get {
        return TopEnumerator.Current;
     }
  }

  object IEnumerator.Current {
     get {
        return Current;
     }
  }

  public IEnumerator<FileSystemInfo> GetEnumerator() {
     return this;
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
     return GetEnumerator();
  }

  IEnumerator<FileSystemInfo> TopEnumerator {
     get {
        if(EnumeratorStack.Count > 0)
           return EnumeratorStack.Peek();

        return null;
     }
  }

  private Boolean ShouldRecurse(FileSystemInfo current) {
     return current != null &&
            IsDirectory(current) &&
            SearchOptions == SearchOption.AllDirectories;
  }

  private Boolean IsDirectory(FileSystemInfo fileSystemInfo) {
     return fileSystemInfo != null &&
            (fileSystemInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory;
  }
}
```

Using it is pretty easy, just instantiate it with the options you want, and then use it like any `IEnumerable`.

```
var fileSystemEnumerator = new FileSystemInfoEnumerator("C:\\Dir", 
    searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories,
    errorHandler: Console.WriteLine);

var lines = from f in fileSystemEnumerator
            select f.FullName + "::" + f.CreationTime.ToShortDateString();

File.WriteAllLines("FileNames.txt", lines);
```

Now obviously this isn't as efficient as the .Net 4.0 one, but the memory footprint should be acceptable. **I tested this on a directory with 50K+ files and it finished in about 5 seconds.**

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5, EnumerateFiles is not available with me :-(